# How does this method use its own method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, methods, recursion, fibonacci

I saw this example about the fibonacci sequence then tested it in IRB. Was hoping someone could break it down for me and show me how it's using the same method inside the method that is being defined.

```
def fib(n)
 return n if (0..1).include? n
 fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) if n > 1
end
```

Comment: It's important to note that in this case, not every call to `fib` would result in another call to `fib`, which is what keeps it from becoming an infinite loop. Too many calls before some return wind up piling up and creating a **Stack Overflow** error. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you define a method with `def whatever(...)` you are doing two things: creating a method, and assigning it to the named method slot.

When you invoke a method in Ruby it will look that up in the local scope; inside the `fib` method that includes the current object on which `fib` is defined.  So, it finds the *current* definition of `fib` and invokes it.

I mention the current part because if the `fib` method redefined `fib` on the current object inside itself the new definition would be used, not the old definition.

That is to say: it will dynamically find the code associated with the *name* each time the name is invoked.

Comment: Thanks Daniel this helps a ton!

Answer (score 3):

It is called recursion...  It is a pattern that comes up in programming at times... If you want to program it is a tool/process you should learn.  Instead of regurgitating here what is already out there, just read what is on wikipedia... Which contains an explanation of the fibonacci sequence which is the defacto example of recursion.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion

Comment: Honestly, I didn't even know this snippet of code was called Recursion which makes it kind of hard to research on what it means.